# How do you express the variogram $\gamma(h)$ in terms of correlation taking into account also the nugget

Tags: correlation, variance, variogram, nugget

let's say that I have a spatial random field $z(\textbf{x})$ with $\textbf{x}$ the spatial coordinate. I can define the semi-variogram as:

$\gamma(h)=\frac{1}{2}E[(z(\textbf{x+h})-z(\textbf{x}))^2]$

This is shown in figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puPOs.jpg):

[image]

It is characterized by the so called nugget, sill and range.

The semi-varigramm is linked to the concept of covariance. I know that it possible to prove that. Can someone show me that but taking also into account the nugget effect? I try to make myself clear. I have found many demonstrations which prove that:

$\gamma(h) = C(0)-C(h)$,

but I would like one demonstration which leads to the nugget effect explicitly. Am I asking something that is not possible? Am not understanding the expression $\gamma(h) = C(0)-C(h)$?

Comment: By your definition, $\gamma(0)$ is zero.

Comment: I adore the jargon "nugget".

Comment: So I have misinterpreted the formula. Thanks, now it is clear. Could you suggest a good prove for $\gamma(h)=C(0)-C(h)$?

Comment: Assuming that by $C(h)$ you mean $Cov(z(x),z(x+h))$ and that your random field is homogeneous, this follows directly from the definition of covariance.

Comment: ok, now it is clear. Thanks. The strongest hypothesis is that the random field is homogeneous. This means that it has constant mean and variance. Am I right?

Comment: I have not get the point yet. You mention that $\gamma(0)=0$ according to my definition. However. I expect that $\gamma(0)=nugget$. Does it depends on how I define $C(h)$ or $C(0)$?